# I can't make the mv command work on a Mac terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal

I am trying to move a file from Downloads to a folder on my desktop.
I keep getting this:

[image]

Why does the usage message appear afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your file has a space in it, so it needs to be escaped. Otherwise, `mv` tries to find a file named "Tres", one named "Beijos_C.pdf" and move them into that directory.

```
# Either...
mv Tres\ Beijos_C.pdf ~/Desktop/choro/

# ...or...
mv "Tres Beijos_C.pdf" ~/Desktop/choro/
```

Comment: Thank you! so I tried it- and this is what happend:

buds-MacBook-Air:~ budaminof$ mv "Tres Beijos_C.pdf" ~/Desktop/choro/
mv: rename Tres Beijos_C.pdf to /Users/budaminof/Desktop/choro/Tres Beijos_C.pdf: No such file or directory
buds-MacBook-Air:~ budaminof$

Comment: and if I can add a question- what does " ~ " before the directory name means? thanks again!

Comment: First, make sure that there is a "choro" directory on your desktop (`mkdir ~/Desktop/choro`). `~` represents your home directory, so it's a shortcut to /Users/budaminof

Comment: Also, make sure that the file exists in your Downloads folder before moving it

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help! everything is there- double check a few times.. still not working. I will keep trying with other folders or file.

Answer (score 0):

If your file name contains spaces, you should surround it with `"` like this:

```
mv "my file name.txt" /home/user/Desktop
```